# Install byobu for normal user in home directory

Tags: server, tmux, gnu-screen, byobu

I use byobu at my local workstation, and would like to use it on the work server too. Unfortunately, I only have normal user rights on the server ( so no sudo apt-get but read/write to the home directory). Both tmux and screen are installed on the server.

The solution would be to install byobu in my home directory, since it seems to essentially be a wrapper around screen/tmux. All the articles I've seen seem to assume superuser rights (for apt-get/yum etc). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Build from source and install in $HOME
see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149394/failed-to-build-byobu-from-source-no-root-permissions)